# Controlling output of Aggregation by multiple columns in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am running the following code:

```
monthly_data = df.groupby(['year','month','name']).agg({'name':'count'})
```

where I am aggregating for a count of names by month over multiple years. The current output is of the form

```
year month game count(name)
....
....
....
```

where the first three values of the output are the index. What I am wanting is to return a dataframe with the names as rows, each year-month combination as a column and count(name) as the value in the column, such that I can plot the time series of the counts of names over time. How can I do this?

edit: the data is of the form

```
year    month    name
2012    1        annie
2012    1        annie
2012    2        david
2012    2        david
2012    2        david
```

the aggregation i does outputs

```
year    month    name    count(name)
2012    1        annie   2
2012    2        david   3
```

I am wanting it to be in the form

```
name    2012-1   2012-2
annie   2        0
david   0        3
```

With the idea that I will be able to create horizon charts with the rows

Comment: Please show us some of your actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't give you exactly the output you wrote, but if you're okay with a miltiindex for your column labels, you could do

```
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, columns = ['year', 'date'], index = 'name', aggfunc = len)
```

If you want it to look exactly like your post:

```
df['date'] = df.apply(lambda row: (row['year'])+'-'+str(row['month']), axis = 1)
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, columns = ['date'], index = 'name', aggfunc = len).reset_index()
```